# How much storage my application is consuming android

Tags: android

Is there a way to know programatically how much storage is being used by an installed application.

applicationInfo: publicSourceDir SourceDir are the only 2 places or there are some other ones when temporary data is stored

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to discover memory usage of my application in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Comment: @Ram Kiran by storage I meant SD card or phone nv memory. Not the RAM. You missunderstood the question